# Advanced numbering with XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an xml structure like this:

```
<nav>
    <group>
        <menu>
            <item>
                <nav>
                   <item></item> 
                </nav>
            </item>
        </menu>  
    </group>
    <group>
        <item></item>
        <item></item>
    </group>
</nav>
```

I want to get this result using XSLT 1.0:

```
<nav id="1">
    <group>
        <menu id="1-1">
            <item id="1-1-1">
                <nav id="1-1-1-1">
                    <item id="1-1-1-1-1"></item> 
                </nav>
            </item>
        </menu>  
    </group>
    <group>
        <item id="1-2"></item>
        <item id="1-3"></item>
    </group>
</nav>
```

It is a bit tricky.

I have been trying using xsl:number but it insists on including the 'group' in the numbering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the system of the `item/@id`s of the second group element?

Answer (score 1):

Now this answer is complete and satisfies your desired output requirements, but I guess it's still not perfect. However, it's the best answer that could be achieved by the given data:

XSLT-1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- modified identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::*) - count(ancestor::group)" />
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:if test="not(../group)">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">      
      <xsl:call-template name="num">
        <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$depth" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="num">
    <xsl:param name="cnt" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::item and $cnt = 0">
        <xsl:variable name="itm" select="count(preceding::item)" />
        <xsl:variable name="grp" select="count(preceding::group) = 0" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$itm + $grp" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'1'" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="$cnt != 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="num">
        <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$cnt - 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nav id="1">
    <group>
        <menu id="1-1">
            <item id="1-1-1">
                <nav id="1-1-1-1">
                    <item id="1-1-1-1-1"/>
                </nav>
            </item>
        </menu>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item id="1-2"/>
        <item id="1-3"/>
    </group>
</nav>
```

as desired.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: So, how would be generated the numbers of the other attributes?

Comment: zx485, I am asking for help. If I had the solution, I would not post a question :-) The logic of the desired numbering seems obvious. Ignore the 'group's and the numbering is straight forward.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: The logic is far from obvious, but I provided an answer that satisfies your desired result.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thanks. However, it only works on my static example. Let's say I have two menus in first group, then it doesn't work. The logic is simple: I want hierarchical numbering disregarding any groups in the structure.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: Yes. I said so. And I also said, repeatedly,  that I cannot perfect this answer without a clear definition of the logic behind the `x-x-x-x-x` values. Or - to put it another way - without a [mcve].

Comment: I have made the logic very clear. The numbering should be hierarchical disregarding any groups. Try look at it without group's, then it would be simple number@level=multiple. I want same but in a structure with group's that should be ignored when numbering. I am not looking for a hardcoded sample based solution, but a generic one.